# urlencode array of my option list

Tags: arrays, select, encode

I've a problem ,I can't decode the options[ragioneSociale] of my select ,I know I should use urldecode() but it gives me error because it wants a string as a paramenter not a multidimensional array!
thank you all

```
 <select id = "lista_clienti" onChange = "getProg(this.value);">
 <option value = "">Scegli cliente</option>
 <?php
     $sql1="SELECT * FROM Clienti";
     $results=$dbhandle->query($sql1); 
     while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo ["IdConto"]; ?>"><?php 
      echo["RagioneSociale"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Iterate over your `options[ragioneSociale]` array in a loop and urlencode each item.

Comment: thank you!!! that was  my idea too but I don't know how concretely write this loop I think it should be something like ?                                                          for(int count = 0; count <= ? ; count++)                                                                         { urldecode($rs);   }

Comment: Read the documentation (http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) or one of many php beginning tutorials.